# Perform action when app is opened after push notification?

Tags: iphone, view, push-notification

I'm trying to figure out push notifications.  I have the method "application did receive remote notification", but this only works when the app is opened by selecting the push notification.  What I am wondering if there is a way to perform an action after the app is opened by touching the app icon, not the notification.  Does this make sense?

I was thinking something like 'if badge number is 1 then do something', but I
 not sure how to implement this.

Comment: When the user taps your app icon, this will be called: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the badge number by calling:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
```